# Ubuntu 14 server edition, how to boot into single-user mode?

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm new in Linux and just have basic knowledge about it. In the past I've tested to boot into single-user mode in some Linux distribution by just append " single" to the boot command. However, I don't know where should I add it in Ubuntu 14, the boot command is actually a shell script. Can anyone help me please? Below are some snapshots I captured.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the answer. At this line:

```
linux /vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root ro
```

append `single` and it becomes to

```
linux /vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root ro single
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>. You will goes into single user mode.

---

To make this permanent, you need to edit `/etc/default/grub` and change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

The details may vary depending on your system. The important bit is setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `text`. Once you have done this, run  `sudo update-grub` and next time you restart you will boot into text mode.

Comment: Exactly, thanks for posting the answer. Are you interested in making this permanent or did you only want it once?

Comment: I only want to do it once. And I found that the way I added ` single` only works one time. The next time I reboot, the ` single` part just disappeared. Do you know how to make it permanent?

Comment: Yup. I just added it to your answer. By the way, please remember to accept this answer once the waiting period is over.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer describes how to make a Linux/GRUB2 host/box boot to single-user mode as the *permanent default* option. One can also make this a permanent but {non-default, menu-selectable} option. One procedure for this (that is not stupid, like editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) is to add a menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` (but see note @ end on menu order):

**1.** *(safety 1st!)* Backup your current `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` . (IIUC, this is part of a default/generic GRUB2 setup.) A **real** filesystem backup is optimal here, but one can also just use the old *backup-to-.0* idiom:

```
    FP_TO_BACKUP='/etc/grub.d/40_custom'
    BACKUP_FP="${FP_TO_BACKUP}.0"
    sudo ls -al "${FP_TO_BACKUP}*"  # checking that you don't already have one
    cp "${FP_TO_BACKUP}" "${BACKUP_FP}"
    sudo chmod a-wx "${BACKUP_FP}"  # non-executable files not used by GRUB2
```

**2.** In your editor of choice, open your current `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. In [Emacs with TRAMP](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode), you can do this from a normal session with the following strings (after `C-x C-f` or `M-x find-file`)

```
    /sudo::/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    /sudo::/etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

**3.** Find your current default menuentry in grub.cfg by searching from top-of-file with regexp=`^menuentry`

**4.** Copy the entire stanza for that menuentry (including the terminal '}' !) to your `40_custom`

**5.** In your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`,

**5.1.** Give the menuentry a useful title. E.g., append `(console)` to whatever you already have.

**5.2.** At least for now, delete most of the code from the original menuentry, keeping only the lines beginning with `set root`, `linux`, `initrd`, and the 2 intervening `echo` lines. (You might also add an explanatory comment.)

**5.3. The important part:** in your line beginning `linux` , replace the code at the end (typically after `ro`) with `single` . E.g.

```
- linux /vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/LVM2_crypt-root ro   nomodeset nouveau.modeset=0
+ linux /vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/LVM2_crypt-root ro single
```

This will make your new menuentry something much simpler than its predecessor, like

```
menuentry 'LMDE 2 Cinnamon 64-bit (console)' {
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/LVM2_crypt-root ro single
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
}
```

**5.3.** Save your `40_custom` and exit your editor.

**6. Don't forget to** `sudo update-grub`

**7.** Reboot: you should now see a persistent item/menuentry at the end of your initial GRUB2 bootscreen.

**Note on menu order:** the new item shows at the end of the generated (by `update-grub`) GRUB2 boot menu, because this procedure edits (the pre-existing) `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. One can change the position of the item in the menu by changing the numeric prefix of the file. A generic GRUB2 `/etc/grub.d/` will contain filenames like

- `00_header` which you probably don't want to edit
- ... followed by themes and other menu decorations
- `10_linux`
- ... followed by Linux-related menuentries
- `30_os-prober`
- ... followed by non-Linux OSs to boot (e.g., Windows)
- `40_custom`
- ... followed by custom menuentries which don't fall into either previous functionality bins

But one can subvert the above schema at will. E.g.,

- to have your custom menuentry show above all the others, give it a numeric prefix < 10. E.g., create a new file `09_custom`
- to have your custom menuentry show after your Linux menuentries but before those for your Windows ones, give it a 10 < numeric prefix < 30. E.g., create a new file `29_custom`

Note that

- the exact numeric-prefix values you must use to achieve a given position will depend on the values already in use on your host/box, so remember to `ls -al /etc/grub.d/`
- if you create a new file, you must make it executable before you `update-grub`