# how to add a custom GRUB2 menuentry to a submenu?

Tags: boot, grub2

My GRUB2 initial boot screen was like

```
LMDE 2 Cinnamon 64-bit
Advanced options for LMDE 2 Cinnamon 64-bit
Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)
```

Note that `Advanced options for LMDE 2 Cinnamon 64-bit` is the title of a GRUB2 `submenu`. As described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401332/38638), I added a custom GRUB2 `menuentry` (for booting to `tty1`) which subsequently (after `sudo update-grub`) appends to my boot screen like

```
LMDE 2 Cinnamon 64-bit
Advanced options for LMDE 2 Cinnamon 64-bit
Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)
LMDE 2 Cinnamon 64-bit (console)
```

My `menuentry` *appended* to my menu because [the above procedure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401332/38638) edits `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to produce (just as an example):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

# TomRoche: added boot to tty1
menuentry 'LMDE 2 Cinnamon 64-bit (console)' {
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/LVM2_crypt-root ro single
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
}
```

I can accept the above behavior, but what I'd *prefer* is for the created `menuentry` to be automagically added to the `submenu`. How to do that without (e.g.) hacking `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` (which on my box has lotsa code related to submenu building)? I.e., I'd prefer to just add some directive to the above `menuentry` (or at least somewhere near it, in the same file) to cause `update-grub` to build the above `menuentry` into the desired `submenu`. Can that be done? If not, what's the least kludgy way to get the above `menuentry` into the `submenu`?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I think you can't append to an existing submenu after its creation... I've read that allegedly the entries from 40_custom are static and just copied... But I might be wrong. But could have a script that just modifies the grub.cfg after `update-grub`. That might be less invasive that modifying 10_linux. That way you can omit the modification if problems occur.

Comment: @rudib: `I think you can't append to an existing submenu after its creation`. What would be the best place to ask about that? `help-grub@gnu.org` ?

Comment: Yes most probably, if not, you could try asking the developers: `grub-devel@gnu.org`

Comment: For openSUSE the manual states: "/boot/grub2/custom.cfg  This optional file is directly sourced by grub.cfg at boot time and can be used to add custom items to the boot menu. Starting with SUSE Linux Enterprise Server these entries will also be parsed when using grub-once."