# Accidentally moved sudoers file

Tags: sudo, raspberry-pi

I accidentally moved /etc/sudoers to Documents.
I need to move it back to /etc, but I can't since I need to be sudo to move files...

```
sudo mv Documents/sudoers /etc

sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: Do you have physical access to the machine? Is there a keyboard & screen attached to it? Can you [boot into single user mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196664/22222)?

Comment: I'm using raspberry pi with sd card

Comment: That doesn't answer any of the three questions I asked :) Do you have physical access to the machine? Is there a keyboard & screen attached to it? Can you [boot into single user mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196664/22222)?

Comment: Sorry i'm new to linux, i'm using Putty for an ssh connection so yes i have keyboard and terminal, it doesn't have what you describe as single user mode

Comment: No, I am asking if you have _physical_ access, so not over putty or ssh. So you're saying there is no keyboard _physically_ connected to the machine and the only way you have to access it is over the network (putty/ssh)?

Comment: Anyway, the updated answer should work for you. It would just have been easier if you had a screen and keyboard connected to the Pi.

Comment: @roaima I think the code you see is actually the user's failed attempt at restoring the file.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2 - if you are using raspberry pi:**

Power down and pull the SD card out from your Pi and put it into your computer.

Open the file `cmdline.txt` and add `init=/bin/sh` to the end or for newer versions: `systemd.unit=emergency.target`. (UPDATE 2) . This will cause the machine to boot to single user mode.

Put the SD card back in the Pi and boot.

When the prompt comes up, type `su` to log in as root (no password needed).

```
mv sudoers-newname sudoers
```

Shut the machine down, then pull the card out again and put the `cmdline.txt` file back the way it was by removing the `init=/bin/sh` bit or **for newer versions: `systemd.unit=emergency.target`.** (UPDATE 2)

(Text adapted for sudoers deletion from here: http://mapledyne.com/ideas/2015/8/4/reset-lost-admin-password-for-raspberry-pi)

**OLD ANSWER:**

If you have root password just issue "su" but if you don't have root password, use a **live** cd, dvd or pendrive to just move the file back again.

For using su just:

```
#su 
Password: Type root password
```

Via the Live-CD open the terminal and:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l (to get a list of partitions)
```

You will see the partition of your linux installation, as something like:

```
/dev/sda1   *                 2048 1936918527 1936916480  923,6G 83 Linux
```

So if in your case it is /dev/sda1 too, just

```
sudo -i
mkdir /mnt/sda1
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
mv /mnt/sda1/etc/sudoers-newname /mnt/sda1/etc/sudoers 
cd /
umount /mnt/sda1
```

If you have your linux installed in multiple partitions, just try mounting one by one until you find the correct one or the one that have the etc files.

That is it. Reboot.

Comment: i'm using a raspberry pi with sd card, how can i fix that?

Comment: A minute please.

Comment: @LightYugen you should be able to boot from the same SD card you originally used to install the OS. If not, see the question I linked to in my comment under your question. When you get to grub, press `e` and edit as described in the "single user mode" section.

Comment: See my edit on the answer.

Comment: https://snag.gy/XzlQcE.jpg did i put it correctly? when i boot it still asks user and password

Comment: Sorry try that instead of init=/bin/sh: systemd.unit=emergency.target -- and then in terminal mount -o remount,rw none /

Comment: see... https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=179344

Answer (score 2):

Booting into single user mode to move the file back to where it belongs is a solution to this problem, and the easiest for a regular PC.

In this case however, the file system is on a SD card. You just need a card reader, that you also need if you want to modify the boot options, and use that to attach the SD card to a regular PC running Linux. If you don't already have a Linux on a PC, get any Linux live CD. Then mount the file system on the card and move the file to the correct place.